# Change the Tab size of tabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, tabcontrol

I redraw the graphics of the `Tab` for the `TabControl` but I can't set the `Width` of it.

What I want is that the text of the `Tab` and the icon is contained in its size.

Now is something like this:

[image: tabs are overlaid]

My Code

```
private void tabControlForm_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{

   try
   {
       using (Brush br = new SolidBrush(TabColors[tabControlForm.TabPages[e.Index]]))
       {
           Rectangle rect = e.Bounds;

           rect.Width += 10;

           e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, rect);
           SizeF sz = e.Graphics.MeasureString(tabControlForm.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font);
           e.Graphics.DrawString(tabControlForm.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, Brushes.Black, rect.Left + (rect.Width - sz.Width) / 2, rect.Top + (rect.Height - sz.Height) / 2 + 1);

           using (var src = new Bitmap(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Castor.Gestionale.images.close-button.png")))
           {
              e.Graphics.DrawImage(src, rect.Right - 18, rect.Top + 10);
           }

           e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkGray, rect);
           e.DrawFocusRectangle();
       }
   }
   catch {}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't built-in property to control the width of the `TabPages'` tab header of the `TabControl` *individually* (Edit: apparently, there is `TabControl.ItemSize` to control it collectively. See TaW's answer to fix the width of all tab pages under a tab control).

But a little trick you could do is to give additional `spaces` in the left or in the right of the `TabPage.Text` to give you enough space for your icon.

Without space:

[image]

With 7 spaces:

[image]

It should be enough to put your icon

Comment: @LorenzoBelfanti "Barbaric" --- I agree. ;) This solution has the benefit of simplicity without losing any built-in Tab header paint & sizing behaviors though. Suppose you re-size the Tab header by custom method, the built-in `Paint` for the Tab header must all be properly overidden

Answer (score 30):

Actually you can set the size of the tabs, but not individually.

The combination of `SizeMode = Fixed` and some suitable value for the `TabControl.Itemsize` will create any size, but always the same..:

[image]

So for individually enlarging each tab to make the icon fit you indeed need to use Ian's 'spacey' method..

Answer (score 7):

Try increasing "myTabControl.Padding.X". It works for me!

Comment: Could get the "X" part to work, but this worked PERFECTLY for me without adding any weird spaces at the end:
this.mytabControl.Padding = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 3);

Answer (score 1):

### Use it...

```
private void FrmSqlMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     myTabControl.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Normal;
     myTabControl.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Also i would like to add one more thing. At first, I tried adding spaces but it didn't seem like working for me. Later, I realized I had to add more spaces than usual to see the difference.